# How to query API server metrics using PromQL?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, promql, metrics-server

I need two metrics from the K8s API server:

1. The total number of requests
2. The times for each request

So far I've tried using these two commands:

```
curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=apiserver_delegated_authn_request_total" | jq
curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=apiserver_delegated_authn_request_duration_seconds_count" | jq
```

But they are both returning the same value with the time (first value) varying slightly:

```
"value": [1685677578.133, "7380"]
```

I believe the value from the response is for the apiserver_delegated_authn_request_total metric. Am I querying this incorrectly? Why are they both returning the same value from the reponse?

Comment: You are querying them correctly. Based on semantics of metrics naming, I'd guess that their same value is by design. Try querying `apiserver_delegated_authn_request_duration_seconds_sum`.